# Change button color to primary on tab in curved navigation bar

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using CurvedNavigationBar as my bottom Navigation Bar. On tap, I want to change this black icon colour to primary colour. But when it is not tapped I want ti as a black colour only. How can I do it?
I tried changing the last three properties of CurvedNavigationBar but not getting the desired output.

Code:

```
 final bottomNavBar = CurvedNavigationBar(
      items: [
        SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/images/hand-shake.svg',
          key: Key('SessionsPage'),
          height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(26),
          width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(26),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/images/home.svg',
          height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(26),
          key: Key("FeedsPage"),
          width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(26),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        Card(
          elevation: 5,
          shape:
              RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)),
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            radius: 24,
            child: Icon(
              Icons.edit,
              color: Colors.black,
              size: 35,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Image.asset(
          'assets/images/booking_icon.png',
          height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(26),
          width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(26),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: usersRef
                .document(CurrentUser().currentUser.databaseID)
                .collection('Alerts')
                .snapshots(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                case ConnectionState.none:
                case ConnectionState.waiting:
                  return Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/images/noti.svg',
                        height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(26),
                        width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(26),
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      CircleAvatar(
                        radius: 2,
                      )
                    ],
                  );

                default:
                  List rev1 = snapshot.data.documents.toList();
                  List res1 = [];

                  for (var i in rev1) {
                    if (i.data['seen'] == false) res1.add(i.documentID);
                  }
                  return Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      SvgPicture.asset(
                        'assets/images/noti.svg',
                        height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(26),
                        width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(26),
                        color: Colors.black,
                      ),
                      res1.length == 0
                          ? CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 2,
                            )
                          : CircleAvatar(
                              radius: 8,
                              backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                              child: Text(
                                res1.length.toString(),
                                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 10),
                              ),
                            ),
                    ],
                  );
              }

              //   child: SvgPicture.asset(
              //     'assets/images/noti.svg',
              //     height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(28),
              //     width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(28),
              //     color: whiteColor,
              // ),
            }),
      ],
      onTap: onTabTapped,
      index: _currentIndex,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      buttonBackgroundColor: whiteColor,
      color: Colors.white,
      height: 60,
    );
    return Scaffold(bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavBar, body: returnBody());
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know this `CurvedNavigationBar` widget, but, looking to your code I can assume that you already have the selected index inside the `_currentIndex` variable.

So, you can just change your items do validate this property to define the correct color:

```dart
CurvedNavigationBar(
      items: [
        SvgPicture.asset(
          'assets/images/hand-shake.svg',
          key: Key('SessionsPage'),
          height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(26),
          width: ScreenUtil().setWidth(26),
          color: _currentIndex == 0 ? Colors.red : Colors.black,
        ),
        // Other items, incrementing the index validation (e.g. == 1, == 2, etc)
      ],
      // Other properties...
);
```

Just change the `Colors.red` to the color you want.

Comment: Works, thanks a lot. Can you also please tell me how I can add a black border or a shadow above the notification bar?

Answer (score 0):

outside the build

```
final colorsNavigation = [
  Colors.purple,
  Colors.amber,
  Colors.orange,
  Colors.red,
  Colors.black26
];
```

inside the build and scaffold

```
bottomNavigationBar: Theme(

      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.white)
      ),
      
      child: CurvedNavigationBar(
        //buttonBackgroundColor: Colors.purple,
        
        index: _page,
        items: bottomNavigationBarItems,
        onTap: (index) {
          
          _pageController.animateToPage(
            index, 
            duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 400), 
            curve: Curves.ease
          );

        },
        
        height: 60,
        //animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        color: colorsNavigation[_page],
        //color: Colors.purple,
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        //key: _bottomNavigationKey,

      ),
    ),
```